# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input. help

Tags: javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    if($('#license_firecorp_checkbox').is(":checked") == true){
      $("#id_license_firecorp").show();

    }

    else{
      $("#id_license_firecorp").hide();
    }

      $("#license_firecorp_checkbox").click(function(){
        if($('#license_firecorp_checkbox').is(":checked") == true){
        $("#id_license_firecorp").show();
    }
      else{
       $("#id_license_firecorp").hide();
       $("#id_license_firecorp").val('');

    }

      })

    if($('#shelf_number_checkbox').is(":checked") == true){
      $("#id_shelf_number").show();
    }

    else{
      $("#id_shelf_number").hide();
    }

   $("#shelf_number_checkbox").click(function(){
    if($('#shelf_number_checkbox').is(":checked") == true){
      $("#id_shelf_number").show();
    }
    else{
      $("#id_shelf_number").hide();
      $("#id_shelf_number").val('');
    }

      })

   if($('#envolve_process_checkbox').is(":checked") == true){
      $("#id_envolve_process").show();

    }

    else{
      $("#id_envolve_process").hide();

    }

   $("#envolve_process_checkbox").click(function(){
    if($('#envolve_process_checkbox').is(":checked") == true){
      $("#id_envolve_process").show();
    }
    else{
      $("#id_envolve_process").hide();
      $("#id_envolve_process").val('');

    }

     })


    if($('#register_employ_checkbox').is(":checked") == true){
      $("#id_register_employ").show();

    }

    else{
      $("#id_register_employ").hide();

    }

   $("#register_employ_checkbox").click(function(){
    if($('#register_employ_checkbox').is(":checked") == true){
      $("#id_register_employ").show();
    }
    else{
      $("#id_register_employ").hide();
      $("#id_register_employ").val('');

    }

    })

    if($('#external_process_checkbox').is(":checked") == true){
      $("#id_external_process").show();

    }

    else{
      $("#id_external_process").hide();

    }

   $("#external_process_checkbox").click(function(){
    if($('#external_process_checkbox').is(":checked") == true){
      $("#id_external_process").show();
    }
    else{
      $("#id_external_process").hide();
      $("#id_external_process").val('');

    }

    })

    if($('#responsability_analise_checkbox').is(":checked") == true){
      $("#id_responsability_analise").show();

    }

    else{
      $("#id_responsability_analise").hide();

    }

   $("#responsability_analise_checkbox").click(function(){
    if($('#responsability_analise_checkbox').is(":checked") == true){
      $("#id_responsability_analise").show();
    }
    else{
      $("#id_responsability_analise").hide();
      $("#id_responsability_analise").val('');

    }

    })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplesmente porque faltou fechar o `$(document).ready(function(){` na última linha:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   if($('#license_firecorp_checkbox').is(":checked") == true){
      $("#id_license_firecorp").show();
   }
   else{
      $("#id_license_firecorp").hide();
   }

   $("#license_firecorp_checkbox").click(function(){
      if($('#license_firecorp_checkbox').is(":checked") == true){
         $("#id_license_firecorp").show();
      }
      else{
         $("#id_license_firecorp").hide();
         $("#id_license_firecorp").val('');
      }
   })

   if($('#shelf_number_checkbox').is(":checked") == true){
      $("#id_shelf_number").show();
   }
   else{
      $("#id_shelf_number").hide();
   }

   $("#shelf_number_checkbox").click(function(){
      if($('#shelf_number_checkbox').is(":checked") == true){
         $("#id_shelf_number").show();
      }
      else{
         $("#id_shelf_number").hide();
         $("#id_shelf_number").val('');
      }
   })

   if($('#envolve_process_checkbox').is(":checked") == true){
      $("#id_envolve_process").show();
   }
   else{
      $("#id_envolve_process").hide();
   }

   $("#envolve_process_checkbox").click(function(){
      if($('#envolve_process_checkbox').is(":checked") == true){
         $("#id_envolve_process").show();
      }
      else{
         $("#id_envolve_process").hide();
         $("#id_envolve_process").val('');
      }
   })


   if($('#register_employ_checkbox').is(":checked") == true){
      $("#id_register_employ").show();
   }
   else{
      $("#id_register_employ").hide();
   }

   $("#register_employ_checkbox").click(function(){
      if($('#register_employ_checkbox').is(":checked") == true){
         $("#id_register_employ").show();
      }
      else{
         $("#id_register_employ").hide();
         $("#id_register_employ").val('');
      }
   })

   if($('#external_process_checkbox').is(":checked") == true){
      $("#id_external_process").show();
   }
   else{
      $("#id_external_process").hide();
   }

   $("#external_process_checkbox").click(function(){
      if($('#external_process_checkbox').is(":checked") == true){
         $("#id_external_process").show();
      }
      else{
         $("#id_external_process").hide();
         $("#id_external_process").val('');
      }
   })

   if($('#responsability_analise_checkbox').is(":checked") == true){
      $("#id_responsability_analise").show();
   }
   else{
      $("#id_responsability_analise").hide();
   }

   $("#responsability_analise_checkbox").click(function(){
      if($('#responsability_analise_checkbox').is(":checked") == true){
         $("#id_responsability_analise").show();
      }
      else{
         $("#id_responsability_analise").hide();
         $("#id_responsability_analise").val('');
      }
   })
}) // ← FALTOU FECHAR AQUI
```

### 2 dicas

**1º.**

Em vez de usar

```
if($('#shelf_number_checkbox').is(":checked") == true)
```

Use

```
if($('#shelf_number_checkbox').is(":checked"))
```

O `== true` é desnecessário nesse caso.

**2º.**

Em vez de usar

```
$("#id_license_firecorp").hide();
$("#id_license_firecorp").val('');
```

Use

```
$("#id_license_firecorp").hide().val('');
```

Não precisa selecionar o mesmo elemento duas vezes seguidas.

### Mais uma dica

Use o `$(this)` para referenciar o elemento alvo do evento. Em vez de

```
$("#license_firecorp_checkbox").click(function(){
   if($('#license_firecorp_checkbox').is(":checked")){
      $("#id_license_firecorp").show();
   }
   else{
      $("#id_license_firecorp").hide().val('');
   }
})
```

Use

```
$("#license_firecorp_checkbox").click(function(){
   if($(this).is(":checked")){
      $("#id_license_firecorp").show();
   }
   else{
      $("#id_license_firecorp").hide().val('');
   }
})
```

Cada *byte* de código economizado pode fazer diferença.

Comment: funcionou, mt obg cara

Comment: Disponha! Adicionei umas diquinhas no final da resposta. Abs!

Comment: @ViniciusMedeirosFogaça quando uma resposta ajuda e você decidir que ela resolveu marque ela como aceita.